# C++ string.find(' ')

Tags: c++, string, find

The goal is to use the `sentence.find('and')` to find all of the positions of *"ands"* in the string. The `int` variable has to be used as well.

> What I've done so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main() {

    string sentence;
    int first, second, third;
    sentence = "My name is Ryan and I like sports and music and movies";
    first = sentence.find('and');
    second = sentence.find('and');
    third = sentence.find('and');

    cout << "Position of first and is: " << first << endl;
    cout << "Position of second and is: " << second << endl;
    cout << "Position of third and is: " << third << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

**It only computes as 18 for all 3**,but I need to find the position of each individual *"and"*. Please help,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the documentation.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Answer (score 1):

The second (obviously optional) argument to `find` specifies where in the string to start searching from; use that to skip over the occurrences you have already found.